# Cambiar el color a un EditText mediante código

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Esta vez estoy haciendo una aplicación la cual consta de una *tabla de 9x3*, cada cuadro compuesto por un *EditText*, allí se ingresan números enteros, los cuales no pueden ir repetidos, ya tengo la función que me identifica cuando están repetidos y mediante un *Toast* me indica en que fila esta el error.

Lo que yo quiero es que además del *Toast* como indicador, se coloreen los cuadros en los que esta el error.

Creo que mi pregunta esta bastante bien formulada y no es necesario agregar código, si necesitan alguna lineal de código me lo comentan y actualizo.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Pues para eso, lo que puedes hacer es crear un `layout` personalizado con el `EditText` y llamarlo cuando sea que quieras que se ejecute

Comment: Un layout por cada error posible? mi tabla es de 9x3, son 27 EditText, tu dices de crear un layout por cada error posible?? Yo tengo creado mi drawable para el EditText con un fondo en blanco, necesitaria crear otro con un fondo en color rojo y saber como invocarlo desde codigo en mi MainActivity

Comment: No, un solo `Layout` que se ejecute en cada error. Es el mismo `Layout` pero ejecutado en tus distintos `EditText` según las condiciones que utilices para validar.

Comment: No entiendo tu respuesta, perdon, quieres una parte de mi codigo para ver?

Comment: Seguro me estoy explicando mal, bien. Tu tienes un `drawable` con un fondo blanco, ¿Verdad? Pues lo que te digo es que crees otro pero con un fondo rojo y que lo ejecutes según tu condición

Comment: Exacto, yo tengo un drawable con fondo blanco, lo uso para cada editText de mi layout. Necesito saber el codigo que puedo usar para que en mi MainActivity cuando yo lo necesite, cambie el drawable de mi EditText numero1 por el drawable de color rojo

Comment: He añadido una respuesta para que se entienda lo que digo

Comment: Hola @FranSchiavone recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask], saludos.

Comment: Java no tiene nada con javascript, y amenos de que estes usando un framework cruzado no deberias haber colocado la etiqueta javascript, hay que borrarla.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modo de ejemplo, tu diseño en blanco:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/blanco"/>

    <stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/negro"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="10px"/>
</shape>
```

Ahora, tu diseño en rojo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/blanco"/>

    <stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/rojo"/>

    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="10px"/>
</shape>
```

En tu código, sería (por ejemplo) algo como esto:

```
            if(loQueSeaQueHagasValidar){
                EditText1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondoblanco);
            }else{
                EditText1.setBackgroundResource(R.fondorojo);
            }
```

Comment: Genial muchas gracias, me sirvió, era justo lo que necesitaba!!

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido :D